# is it Okay to use 'return' in react lifecycle method besides shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, redux

is it Okay to use 'return' in react lifecycle method besides shouldComponentUpdate?

I have some if statements in my componentWillUpdate method and if the first condition does not meet, I want to avoid the rest if statements to be run.

Comment: Why don't you use `else` ? Please add [mcve] so people can understand better of what you are trying to do.

Comment: In react docs it is not mentioned if they are using returned value of `componentWillUpdate` in any way. So yes it is okay.

Comment: How did you end up fixing your code?

Answer (score 0):

Such logic goes in shouldComponentUpdate. componentWillUpdate is just your last opportunity to take actions before the component actually updates, but you can't stop it at this point.

Or if I misunderstood you, and you want to not execute the `else` statement if the first `if` does not meet.. then you should rearrange your if statement. I.e. check if the condition does meet... Or use `else if`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this diagram you cannot stop lifecycle after shouldComponentUpdate. shouldComponentUpdate is the place you want to stop the lifecycle.

[image]